# If I remove all my upvotes from a user's posts which I upvoted, will it be considered as serial voting fraud?

Tags: discussion, support, serial-voting

If I remove all my upvotes from a user's posts which I ever upvoted, will it be considered as serial voting fraud?

Can I be blocked for doing so?

Note: Just a question. I have no intention of doing it.

Comment: Why would you want to? Has your opinion on the *post* changed? or just the user?

Comment: @Sayse i just asked, i'm not thinking of doing it.

Comment: Unless all of those upvotes were in the last ten minutes, or all of the questions were edited in that window, you can't do it anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't be thinking about voting fraud. It's a bit weird that you changed your mind on many posts, at the same time.

When you vote on a post, you should consider its quality, not the user behind it. You're not helping yourself or anyone else by deciding to vote based on the user and not the quality - It's considered a very bad thing to do, and yes, your votes will be undone when the system detects suspicious voting pattern.

Also keep in mind that your vote is locked after a few minutes, and can only be reversed when the post you voted on is edited.

Comment: And another thing: Your vote is locked only after a few minutes. Once you make a vote, you can reverse it in a few minutes. I know post editing will unlock the post. But then your line: _Also keep in mind that your vote is locked until an edit is made._ is wrong. It is saying that the vote will be locked till an edit is made. I think you should change it to: _Also keep in mind that your vote is locked after a few minutes, and can only be reversed when the post you voted on is edited_ or something with the same meaning.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ Good point, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For some time now you **can't change your votes as they will be locked**, and an alert appears if we try to modify the votes of a previous question.